# Magento 2: How to pass the payment method configuration value to the html template

Tags: magento2, module, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I have deploy a payment gateway module based on the sample from github https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway.

At this point, I'm trying to show additional information that were set on the admin configuration on the `/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html`. However, there only few methods that I can try to get the data from: `getCode()`, `getTitle()`, etc. What I'm trying to get is another field (let's say FieldA, which is defined as field_a on the admin xml config file under etc folder.

I checked on the variable `window.checkoutConfig`, but it did not seem to show much information that were set from the payment configuration on the admin.

Am I missing a step before I can pass the config data into the block file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all,** it's hard to check the json if we don't use a format tool.

We can use this website to render json: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

[image]

**Second:**

I'm going to add and get the new field - fixed fee amount to our payment.

--Get fixed amount in config provider.

**sample-module-payment-gateway/Model/Ui/ConfigProvider.php**

```
final class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{


    const CODE = 'sample_gateway';

    protected $method;

    /**
     * Payment ConfigProvider constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
    ) {
        $this->method = $paymentHelper->getMethodInstance(self::CODE);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment' => [
                self::CODE => [
                    'transactionResults' => [
                        ClientMock::SUCCESS => __('Success'),
                        ClientMock::FAILURE => __('Fraud')
                    ],
                    'fixedamount' => $this->getFixedAmount(),
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
    //Get fixed amount
    protected function getFixedAmount()
    {
        return $this->method->getFixedAmount();
    }
}
```

--Get fixed amount from payment js

**sample-module-payment-gateway/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/sample_gateway.js**

```
        getFixedAmount: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.sample_gateway.fixedamount;
        },
```

--Add to the payment template

**sample-module-payment-gateway/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
     ......
     <div class="fixed-amount">
        <span data-bind="text: getFixedAmount()"></span>
     </div>
     ......
</div>
```

--Add to our admin config:

**sample-module-payment-gateway/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<field id="fixedamount" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="53" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Fixed Amount</label>
                    <frontend_class>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</frontend_class>
</field>
```

--Last but not least, remember to run static content deploy again.

Comment: Hi there.. I ran into some issue. I defined getFixedAmount: function() in "sample_gateway.js" file with some arbitrary value instead of function call. On the checkout page, it threw an error that getFixedAmount from  <span data-bind="text: getFixedAmount()"></span> as:  

knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return getReferralCode() }" Message: getReferralCode is not defined

Any idea?

Comment: I have tried to deploy the static content, but that didn't seem to help either. Note that this site is not in the production mode.

Comment: Go to `Admin > STORES > Configuration`, try to add a value. You can check the current checkout config in checkout page with http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: So at this point adding the field system.xml works. I was able to enter the data and save it. When I refresh the page does load. Now I take a step back to ConfigProvider.php and notice that the checkout page would not even load if the code try to do $this->getFixedAmount(), which essentially call $this->method->getFixedAmount(). Do we need any extra file outside the demo sample project to be able to access to the configuration? Thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: I tried to add some arbitary getSomething function on the sample_gateway.js, which return "hello world" text. Turned out when i tried to bind it to a span, such  <span data-bind="text: getSomething()"></span>, it threw the same getSomething is not defined. Do we have to do something extra in order to reflect the change on the JS file beside run station content deploy?

Comment: After some isolation, looks like there is some issue with $this->method->getFixedAmount(); when it is called, the HTTP return error 500. When i tried  return $this->method->getTitle(); I didn't get the error, though. Looks like something is funky with the custom field.

Comment: So looks like I'm down to couple issue. Somehow  $this->method = $paymentHelper->getMethodInstance(self::CODE); in ConfigProvider.php return empty object. and also the sample_payment.js file on the method-renderer doesn't seem to do anything even when I change the code in there. Any ideas? Sorry for the stacked up comments.

Comment: @Frostshoxx's comment: For whatever reason `getFixedAmount()` will get function undefined error. So I try the more primitive way with `getConfigData("fixedamount")`. Every thing including the js and template part also works.